# Mathjax and markdown syntax conflicts in xaringan

Tags: r, xaringan

I'm using `xaringan` for my presentations for a while now and I never had any issue including math equations using MathJax, but I'm currently running into a problem. Let say I want to create those simple two equations in a `xaringan` presentation.

```
---
output: xaringan::moon_reader
---

$$
a^{*}
$$

$$
a^{*} + b^{*}
$$
```

[image]

As one can see, the first one will be rendered properly by MathJax, but not the second one. I suspect this is due to some interaction between the markdown syntax and the MathJax equation (we can see that the * are gone and that the `b` is in italic). However, both equations render with no problem in a regular `html_document`.

Someone could help me render both equations in a `xaringan` presentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the math expressions right after `$$` on the same lines, e.g.,

```
---
output: xaringan::moon_reader
---

$$a^{*}$$

$$a^{*} + b^{*}$$
```

Comment: That was so simple haha! Thanks @Yihui Xie